# Scroll up and down line by line (from buffer) in c

Tags: c, terminal, scroll

I write code to extract data from xmltv listings and display them in osd page with 15 line.
How to make to scroll up and down line by line in page until information from listings perchannel is end and them move to next page that display information for another channel?

channel 1:

```
|   line1   |                      |   line2   |                |-----------|
|   line2   |                      |   line3   |                |-----------|
|   line3   | scroll down line =>  |   line4   | then clear =>  | lastline  | 
|   line4   |                      |-----------|                |           |
|-----------|                      |   line15  |                |           |
|   line15  |                      |   line16  |                |           |
```

then move to => channel 2:

```
|   line1   |                      |   line2   |                |-----------|
|   line2   |                      |   line3   |                |-----------|
|   line3   | scroll down line =>  |   line4   | then clear =>  | lastline  |
|   line4   |                      |-----------|                |           |
|-----------|                      |   line15  |                |           |
|   line15  |                      |   line16  |                |           |
```

etc.

---

code:

```
int epg_show_perchannel( tvtime_osd_t* osd, int page, station_mgr_t *stationmgr, xmltv_t *xmltv, int channel )
{
if (!page)
    return 0;
if ( xmltv ){
    const int buf_length = 255;
    const int max_num_lines = 15;
    const int num_stations = station_get_num_stations( stationmgr );
    char *old_channel = strdup( xmltv_get_channel( xmltv ) );
    char buf[buf_length+1];
    int i, cur = 0;
    time_t curtime = time( 0 );
    const char *xmltv_id = 0;

    if (channel > num_stations)  
        channel = 1;
    else if (channel < 1 )
        channel = num_stations;

    if (!(xmltv_id = station_get_xmltv_id( stationmgr, channel-1 ))) 
        xmltv_id = xmltv_lookup_channel( xmltv, station_get_name( stationmgr, channel-1 ));
    xmltv_set_channel( xmltv, xmltv_id);
    xmltv_refresh_withtime( xmltv, curtime );

    /* Header with channel number + name */
    snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%d Next on [%s] %s:", channel, station_get_channel(stationmgr,channel-1), station_get_name( stationmgr, channel-1));
    tvtime_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, buf );
    tvtime_osd_list_set_hilight(osd, -1);   

    for( i = 0; i < max_num_lines; i++ ) {
        xmltv_refresh_withtime( xmltv, curtime );

        if (xmltv_get_title( xmltv )) {
            char start_time[50];
            time_t start_timestamp = xmltv_get_start_time( xmltv );
            time_t end_timestamp = xmltv_get_end_time( xmltv );
            strftime( start_time, 50, "%H:%M", localtime( &start_timestamp ) );

            /* starttime of current program + Now showing program */
            snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%s %s", start_time, xmltv_get_title( xmltv ));       
            if (xmltv_get_sub_title( xmltv )){
                strncat(buf," (",buf_length-strlen(buf));  
                strncat(buf,xmltv_get_sub_title( xmltv ),buf_length-strlen(buf));
                strncat(buf,")",buf_length-strlen(buf));  
            }
            tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext( osd, cur++, buf, 1);

            if (!xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv )) {
                char end_time[50];
                /* no next program, print endtime of current programme */       
                strftime( end_time, 50, "%H:%M", localtime( &end_timestamp ) );
                snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%s %s", end_time, "");       
                tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext( osd, cur++, buf, 1);
            }
        curtime = end_timestamp;

        } else {
            /* No XMLTV information for this channel */
            tvtime_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, "");
        }

    }
    tvtime_osd_list_set_lines( osd, cur );
    tvtime_osd_show_list( osd, 1, 1 );

    xmltv_set_channel(xmltv, old_channel);
    free(old_channel);
    xmltv_refresh( xmltv );

} else {
    tvtime_osd_list_set_text( osd, 0, "No XMLTV information available" );
    tvtime_osd_list_set_lines( osd, 1 );
    tvtime_osd_show_list( osd, 1, 1 );
}
return channel;
}
```

code, current show page with only 15 line and then move to next channel.

I want to scroll down list until information from xmltv listings for channel is end (contains information for 3-4 days), and then move to next channel:

[image: screenshoot]

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: you should take a look at how `more` and `less` are implemented.

Comment: What you put in your example is a scroll __down__ not a scroll up. If you scroll up you go to the upper lines and so you will hide line15 and reveal line0

Comment: @Coren: Exactly what you said. It uses termcap (I think), compared to which NCurses is favored, or something like that. But in a nutshell, NCurses is the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The applications mentioned in the comments do the scrolling on a *terminal* (possibly with terminal escape sequences), but you seem to be displaying the text with some special API, on something that cleary doesn't look like a terminal, so I guess that approach won't work.

You should just recreate the texts, maybe you have to remove the previous texts, honestly I have no idea... check the documentation.